# What coordinate system is this and where is it located in google maps?

Tags: coordinate-system, nigeria

I have coordinates of a landed property somewhere near Benin city, Nigeria. Coordinates are given as:

248 600.773 mN
347 786.232 mE

Where is this location in Google maps?

Comment: It should be somewhere in the "Evbovbioba" area, postal code 300102. Approximate location of this postal code is lat 6.21839, lon 5.5269. Still, I would like to know the exact location of the property as indicated by the unknown coordinates above.

Answer (score 2):

Using my [projection guesser](http://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections/2017/01/06/finding-a-projection.html) the closest answer I can find is:

[EPSG:26391](http://epsg.io/26391)

WKT:

```
PROJCS["Minna / Nigeria West Belt", 
  GEOGCS["Minna", 
    DATUM["Minna", 
      SPHEROID["Clarke 1880 (RGS)", 6378249.145, 293.465, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7012"]], 
      TOWGS84[-111.92, -87.85, 114.5, 1.875, 0.202, 0.219, 0.032], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6263"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4263"]], 
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", 4.5], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 4.0], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.99975], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 230738.26], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","26391"]]
```

Comment: The property should be somewhere in the proximity of Benin city. Few kilometers south of city centre. This one is way off from where it should be.